# E​l​u​c​idation

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

Your final answer should describe the legibility of this puzzle.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To start off,

> the right side looks to be four lines of text. We can divide the pixels up into 3×3 chunks to read them:
>
>  [image: right side of image, cut into chunks]
>
>  `DONT EXIST`
>  `USES A FOIL`
>  `NEVER-BEFORE-SEEN`
>  `TYPE OF CAKE`

Alright, those seem important. But what about the other side?

> Well, the colorful rectangle at the bottom appears to be divisible in the same way:
>
>  [image: colorful rectangle divided into 3×3 chunks]
>
>  This looks like the numbers `123456789`.
>  And there are similar shapes appearing in the top...

This leads to the main aha moment of the puzzle:

> The top left can be cut up the same way too -- but parts are being obscured by the number squares at the bottom! So the second and third letters of the first row are 8 (rotated) and 9; on the far right of that row, we have 7, but it's been rotated and color-flipped.
>
>  The colors help us disambiguate some identical-looking numbers, like 2 and 5, and 1 and 4. (Though 6 and 9 aren't disambiguated.)
>
>  [image: top left cut up into 3×3 chunks]
>
>  Now the clues make sense - they're giving hints as to what's underneath the squares. For instance, the second row is pretty readable already as `D?E[L/C][S/J]`: given the clue "USES A FOIL", the answer must be `DUELS`.
>
>  So we can fill in DUELS, using the font on the right as a reference for the "official" letter shapes.

Then we can continue, and reveal what was previously hidden:

> The answers to the clues are `ARENT`, `DUELS`, `NOVEL`, and `LAYER`.
>
>  [image: 4×5 grid of 3×3 pixel letters]
>
>  There are a few ambiguities in the tiles (which is 6 and which is 9? is 8 rotated or flipped?). But these can all be resolved, since all but one option for each will give you a non-letter.

So, the legibility of this puzzle is:

> [image]
>
>  **EXECRABLE**!